# SQL dynamic group by varying number of columns

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, group-by

I need the to dynamically change GROUP BY clause rule for grouping.
Always returns the same number and names of columns.

For example in table:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
  employee_id NOT NULL,
  department_id integer,
  status character varying(50), /*active/inactive*/
  cost numeric,
  income (numeric),
  first_name character varying(50),
  last_name character varying(50)
)
```

I need to query something like this:

```
select 
    count(employee_id) as contacts,
    sum(cost) as cost,
    sum(income)/count(employee_id) as average_salary
from 
    employees
group by
    case
        when status = 'active' then /*group by*/ department_id, employee_id
        when status = 'inactive' then /*group by*/ employee_id
    end;
```

How I can run this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, what do you want to achieve: you can use `GROUP BY` on any expression, not just on columns.

You can use the variant below, if you want to separate inactive employees and all department's employees from each other:

```
-- ...
GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN status = 'active'   THEN department_id
           WHEN status = 'inactive' THEN NULL
         END,
         employee_id
```

But the solution above will accumulate all inactive employees with all other who hasn't assigned to departments (`department_id IS NULL`). If that does not concern you, this is the most simple solution.

You can use [row constructors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) too:

```
-- ...
GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN status = 'active'   THEN ROW(department_id, employee_id)
           WHEN status = 'inactive' THEN ROW(employee_id)
         END
```

But be aware how [their comparison](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON) works.

**Note**: When you use `employee_id` in `GROUP BY`, then `COUNT(employee_id)` will always be `1`.